# Setting favicon with FastAPI?

Tags: python, favicon, fastapi

How do I set a favicon for all pages in my `FastAPI` project?

Comment: That would depend on how you serve your HTML; that would have a reference to the favicon and the browser would load that file. If you need FastAPI to serve the static resource, look at the static file support of FastAPI; otherwise - please elaborate what you're missing and how you're servering your HTML now.

Comment: Do I need to serve any sort of html at all for it to work? I thought there might be a way to make a favicon appear when doing plain url based post and get requests in a browser.

Comment: A browser would by default make a request for `/favicon.ico` in that case; you'll need to serve a file under that path if that's what you're looking for (this will assume that your endpoint returns the actual answer to the request). You could add a `@router.get('/favicon.ico')` and return a FileResponse in that view: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse

Answer (score 48):

Just return a `FileResponse` in the GET request to `/favicon.ico`

File structure:

```
root
|-main.py
|-favicon.ico
```

`main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

app = FastAPI()
favicon_path = 'favicon.ico'

@app.get('/favicon.ico', include_in_schema=False)
async def favicon():
    return FileResponse(favicon_path)
```

The keyword `include_in_schema=False` included in the decorator hides the path operation from the schema used to autogenerate API docs.

Comment: You might want to include a `include_in_schema=False` in the decorator to hide this route from the schema.

Comment: So, in Dec 2021, i think they added FileResponse to the main library.  I was able to do the same thing with the following import instead of the import from starlette.

```
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
```

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue and dorked around trying different things and it only started working after I mounted folder for static files.

In main.py

```
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

In home.html head area

```
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="static/images/favicon.ico">
```

I suspect it's related to folder permissions.